# Почему при открытии exe-файла код не работает, хотя в терминале vs 2022 всё нормально?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Пытаюсь открыть файл `.exe` с `C#` проектом консольного приложения,но оно мгновенно открывается и закрывается. Код должен просто вывести переменную и всё. Что делать в таком случае? Причём в терминале vs 2022 всё работает.

Код:

```
string name = "саша";
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зелёную галочку слева от него

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переменную-то ваше приложение вывело, но вот вы этого не увидели, потому что сразу после этого приложение завершило свою работу.

Консоль в VS ожидает по завершению работы приложения нажатия любой кнопки. В приложении это нужно делать самостоятельно. Добавьте в конце `Console.ReadKey();`

Comment: Не учите плохому, не надо Console.ReadKey делать!

Comment: @PavelMayorov в данном конкретном случае чем плох Console.ReadKey? В шарпы добвили что-то для предотвращения закрытия окна по завершении процесса?

Comment: @PavelMayorov для данного случая лучше, чем ReadLine. А если уж совсем по-честному делать, то `Console.WriteLine("Нажмите любую клавишу..."); Console.ReadKey(true);` - почти продакшн код. xD

Comment: @Zufir Console.ReadKey плох тем, что нарушает соглашения о том как должна работать консольная утилита. При запуске её из, собственно, консоли, придётся нажимать эту самую клавишу каждый раз. А уж как проклянёт эту строчку тот, кто попытается вызвать программу из пакетного файла...

Comment: @PavelMayorov any key в stdin, и дело сконцом xD

Comment: @PavelMayorov как в данном случае предлагаете организовать вывод результата, чтобы его смог увидеть пользователь? Пакетный запуск для Hello world - сценарий настолько гипотетический, что я даже не знаю, что и сказать по этому поводу. Это не pkzip, не rar32. Когда человек сможет писать пакетные утилиты - он таки будет уже понимать, что он может делать с консолью, а чего не может.

Comment: @Zufir helloworld нужен чтобы потренироваться писать реальные утилиты, потому я и говорю не учить плохому. А увидеть результат проще всего нажав F5 в студии.

Answer (score 2):

Альтернативный вариант:

Приложение консольное, ну так и запустите его не двойным кликом, а по честному. Запустите консоль (cmd.exe), перейдите в папку с файлом вашего приложения и вызовите его явно по имени. Можно не переходить в папку приложения, а просто указать полный путь к файлу и вызвать откуда угодно.

В этом случае окно консоли будет принадлежать cmd.exe, а не вашему приложению и оно не закроется автоматически, как в случае с запуском приложения двойным кликом, а будет ждать дальнейших команд от вас. Собственно именно так и поступает студия, когда запускает приложение по кнопке run, только студия делает это все "за кадром".

Данный вариант более предпочтителен, чем явная постановка приложения на пазу путем добавлением подтверждения завершения работы пользователем, т.к. подтверждение не всегда уместно и в случае более сложного приложения, позволит увидеть причину незапланированного "вылета", если забыли обработать какую-то исключительную ситуацию например.