# Почему не выводиться русский текст в консоль из Windows компилятора C#?

Tags: c#, windows, input, русификация

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace Sample {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            Console.WriteLine("Даров!");
        }
    }
}
```

После компиляции он выдает мне пустую строчку и вылетает, как будто произошла утечка памяти.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
С чем это может быть связано? Как это решить?

PS. Кодировка стоит UTF-8, а Компилятор Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2008 версии 3.5.30729.9141 для Microsoft (R) .NET Framework версии 3.5

Comment: Зачем вы задаете кодировку явно, если без этого все работает?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1537731/220553

Comment: Необработанное исключение: System.IO.IOException: Параметр задан неверно.

   в System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   в System.Console.set_InputEncoding(Encoding value)
   в Sample.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: Вы мой посыл не так поняли как я погляжу... Ну ок, перефразирую: Ваша проблемы высосана из пальца, ибо вы стандартное поведении консоли приняли за баг. Консоль - это тот код, который вы написали, не более. Вот написали вы вывод на экран, ок, вам вывело, но вы не просили консоль ждать вашей реакции, ваших действий, она и не ждет, а просто закрывается. Чтоб она ждала, вам надо это явно указать в коде, например `Console.ReadLine();`, после этого она выдаст текст и будет ждать нажатия. Ну а теперь подумайте, при чем тут кодировка? И какая к черту "утечка памяти"? Это все ваши выдумки, не более...

Answer (score 0):

Крч, решение простое. Есть два способа либо просто убрать Encoding либо не пытаться скормить Винде юникод, а оставить UTF8

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace Sample{
    class Program{
        static void Main(string[] args){
            Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;  
            Console.WriteLine("Даров!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace Sample{
    class Program{
        static void Main(string[] args){
            Console.WriteLine("Даров!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

PS. Пишу в первую очередь для тех, кто напорется на данный вопрос, ведь новичков в C# не мало, а GPT нормально не объясняет почему.

Comment: Всё верно, Encoding.Unicode это UTF-16, а оно не поддерживается в консоли. Для разработки только используйте более свежую студию, например 2022, она бесплатная есть на сайте майкрософта, а проект создавайте не под Framework, а под .NET 6 или новее. А то "чем дальше в лес, тем толще партизаны" будут.